# How to get json_encode value when using $.post() ajax call

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have successfully perform the $.post ajax call, but can not able to fetch data after some specific operation,

```
if ($updateUserResult) {
        $response ['userId'] = $userId;
    }

    json_encode ( $response );
```

where `$updateUserResult` is boolean. on my js file

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    var data = $(form).serialize();
    $.post("test.php", data).done(function( response ) {
         console.log(response);
      });
    return false;
}
```

console log displays empty. Am I missing somthing or the flow is wrong..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to echo the output:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 2):

To send the output you need to echo it:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

and parse it success callback.

```
var data=JSON.parse(response);

console.log(data.userId);//will log userid
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use echo statement:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
please check
```

$.ajax({

```
type: "POST",
url: "API_URL", 
data: {consultantId: consultantId
},
success: function(data){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));       
}
});
```